# Dynamic parameter of table name in Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

I was doing something like

```sql
select * from $P{TABLENAME_VAR}
```

in JR report but I am getting invalid table name exception though the parameter contain proper table name

The scenario here is I want to populate the name of the  table dynamically based on the input provided by the user so what I am doing is

I have created a parameter . Now based on the input selected by the user a particular table name is assigned to this variable but when I am trying to assign this parameter as table name in report I am getting `Invalid table name` exception.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to this one just do

```
select * from $P!{TABLENAME_VAR}
```

instead of

```
select * from $P{TABLENAME_VAR}
```

Comment: Don't forget you can mark it as the accepted answer since you solved your own problem. (Well there is a short time period you have to wait, but I think you should be able to shortly, if not already.)